# Derive from template argument and call its copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, derived

Please consider the following code:

```
template<class basic_ios_type>
class basic_ios_adaptor;

template<template<typename, class> class basic_ios_type, typename char_type, class traits_type>
class basic_ios_adaptor<basic_ios_type<char_type, traits_type>>
    : public basic_ios_type<char_type, traits_type>
{
public:
    typedef basic_ios_type<char_type, traits_type> base_type;

    basic_ios_adaptor(base_type const& other)
        : base_type(other)
    {
    }
};
```

The only available constructor is a copy constructor which takes a const reference to the base type.
Example usage:

```
std::ofstream                    x(std::ofstream(""));  // ok
basic_ios_adaptor<std::ofstream> y(std::ofstream(""));  // error
```

Visual C++:

> 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
>   : cannot access private member
>   declared in class
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Intel:

> no instance of constructor
>   "std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,
>   _Traits>::basic_ofstream [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" matches the argument list

Could anybody explain to me why this isn't working?

Comment: What does it mean to copy a stream? A stream is not a container, but a flow of data.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer - It's not yoir code, it's not your coding standard.

Comment: @Yochai: No. Don't start class names with capitals. Name one C++ standard type that starts with a capital.

Comment: Naming conventions for templates, another discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692752/naming-conventions-for-template-types

Comment: @Tomalak - you can copy a stream (like I showed above). But I cannot do it by using my adaptor class.

Comment: From Boost naming consistency: "Template parameter names begin with an uppercase letter." http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html#Naming_consistency

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: Actually you didn't. That "copy" was elided. In a fit of ghastliness, the compiler is allowed to elide the copy-from-temporary even if it would have "side effects". These side effects might be output to console or, in this case, a compiler error.

Comment: @Yochai: Template parameter names are not the same as class template names.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, didn't mean the class name. meant the template parameters.

Comment: @Tomalak: A private copy constructor can not be elided, and a compile error is not a side effect.

Comment: @Dennis: Then explain it. [Streams cannot be copied.](http://ideone.com/a6IO8)

Comment: @Tomalak: Moves. See my answer below. I confirmed this behavior on VS2010, but the version of gcc ideone uses doesn't implement it yet.

Comment: @Dennis: Since [pre-0x GCC won't elide this like I thought it would](http://ideone.com/KK2tC), I'm now inclined to agree with you. Regardless, "it isn't a copy" is still accurate, and streams still cannot be copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't copy streams, because their copy constructor is private (or more specifically, the copy ctor from `basic_ios`).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed).

Answer (score 4):

STL streams cannot be copy constructed, thats your problem.

Comment: Why it's working for std::ofstream? (`std::ofstream x(std::ofstream(""))`)

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: It's not. You're not copying. See my comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, standard streams are not copiable.  However, in C++0x, they are *moveable*.  Depending on what compiler/setting you are using, that is likely the behavior you are seeing.  `ofstream x(std::ofstream("x"));` creates a temporary `ofstream`, and then moves that temporary into the named `ofstream`.  This is perfectly legal.  However, in your code, you define a copy constructor, so no move can take place.  Copies are still forbidden, so the compiler stops you.

So, for your class, you would also have to move, not copy.  `ios_base_adaptor(base_type&& other) : ofstream(std::move(other)) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what I want to achieve is the possibility to create any basic_ios<> class I derive from. So, in my example I just wanted to create a ofstream for the specified file.

It's possible in the following way:

```
template<template<typename, class> class basic_ios_type, typename char_type, class traits_type>
class basic_ios_adaptor<basic_ios_type<char_type, traits_type>>
    : public basic_ios_type<char_type, traits_type>
{
public:
    typedef basic_ios_type<char_type, traits_type> base_type;

    template<class create>
    basic_ios_adaptor(create& create)
    {
        create(static_cast<base_type*>(this));
    }
};
```

It should be safte to pass a pointer to the base class, because at this stage it's already allocated and constructed.

Usage:

```
struct construct
{
    void operator()(std::ofstream* o) { 
        *o = std::ofstream("file");
    }
};

construct c;
basic_ios_adaptor<std::ofstream> y(c);
```

Any other workaround?

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: It's an answer, because it seems to work. But this depends on the compiler if he elides it or not (see comments on my initial post).

Comment: While my comments regarding elision were wrong, streams still cannot be copied. I think what you're doing here is _moving_, which is new to C++0x. As long as you're aware of it, and as long as your code is aware of it, you might be ok...